# How to add a conditional statement to an object?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like after entering the number "GoodAnswer" to check whether I entered a number from 0 to 3
I would like to make sure that people don't enter numbers out of range
I enter 4 questions and answers, I would like the condition to check well after pressing the button. I have a problem with this. Sorry for my english

```cs
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            var question = new Question()
            {

                Answers = new List<string> {
                    odpowiedzEntry1.Text, odpowiedzEntry2.Text, odpowiedzEntry3.Text, odpowiedzEntry4.Text },
                GoodAnswer = odpowiedzPrawidlowa.Completed += async (sender, e) => { int response = int.Parse(odpowiedzPrawidlowa.Text) if (response >= 0 && response < 4)
                    {

                    } 
                    else {

                        await DisplayAlert("", "Wrong range", "ok");

                    } }  ,
                Question1 = zagadkaEntry.Text
                };




            var questionPage = new QuestionPage(question);
            questionPage.Disappearing += QuestionPageClosed;


            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(questionPage);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Answers = new List<string> {
                odpowiedzEntry1.Text, odpowiedzEntry2.Text, odpowiedzEntry3.Text, odpowiedzEntry4.Text },
                GoodAnswer = Convert.ToInt16(odpowiedzPrawidlowa.Text),
                Question1 = zagadkaEntry.Text
            });
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var result = await client.PostAsync("", content);
        }
};
```

Comment: the use OnCompleted event of the Entry

Comment: @Jason any example??

Comment: Okay. We know what you would like. So, what's your _question_? Where is your [mcve] that shows exactly what you've tried? Where is your explanation of what _specifically_ you need help with? What are you actually _asking_?

Answer (score 0):

use the `Completed` event of `Entry`

```
myEntry.Completed += (s,e) {

  // should use TryParse or try/catch here
  int response = int.Parse(myEntry.Text);

  if (response > 0 & response < 4) {
    // do something
  }
}
```